# Render ref dynamically with variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, mapping, ref

I've a function that maps an object and return a list of items dynamically. Now i wish to access the inputRef for each of this element's list to apply some effect, but it is only being applied on the last and current element, and not on the rendered items

This is the rendering function:

```
renderSortByOptions() => {
  return Object.keys(this.sortByOptions).map((sortByOption) => {
    let sortByOptionValue = this.sortByOptions[sortByOption];
    return (
      <li
        className={this.getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)}
        key={sortByOptionValue} 

        ref={this.inputRef} // <====

        onClick={this.handleSortByChange.bind(this, sortByOptionValue)}
      >
        {sortByOption}
      </li>
    );
  });
};
```

The ref is happening on the componentDidUpdate like this:

```
componentDidUpdate();
  {
    if (this.state.showMenu === true) {
      let words = ["viejos", "nuevos", "menor", "mayor"];
      words.forEach((item, i) => {
        this.styleWord(this.inputRef.current, item);
      });
    }
  }
```

And this is just the styleWord function:

```
styleWord(target, word) {
  let html = target.innerHTML;
  html = html.replace(new RegExp(word, "g"), "<i>" + word + "</i>");
  target.innerHTML = html;
};
```

Comment: Can you share a sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **InputRefArrary for holding reference** of multiple inputs that you created dynamically. Here is an example. Please check it.

```
import React from "react";

export default class MultipleTextField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.inputArr = ["name", "age", "gender"];
        this.inputRefArr = [this.inputArr.length];
        this.inputArr.map((input, index) => {
            this.inputRefArr[index] = React.createRef();
        });
        this.state = {values: [this.inputArr.length]};
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    }

    onChange = (event, index) => {
        // 1. Make a shallow copy of the values
        let values = [...this.state.values];
        values[index] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({values}, () => {
            console.log(values, 'values')
        });
    };

    clickHandler = (event) => {
        this.inputArr.map((input, index) => {
            alert(`${input} is ${this.state.values[index]}`)
        })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                {
                    this.inputArr.map((input, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <label key={index}>
                                    {input}
                                    <input key={index} ref={this.inputRefArr[index]} id="message" type="text"
                                           value={this.state.values[index]}
                                           onChange={(event) => this.onChange(event, index)}/>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                }
                <input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick={this.clickHandler}/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Khabir, thanks for your reply, i understand the idea but still can't apply it on my example, i'll continue checking :)